# Transform ansible variable value based on input

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Total noob here learning Network Automation using Ansible with Jinja2.

I need to determine a range command based on the number of switches in a stack, for example, i ask for input in the playbook, something along the lines of "How many switches in your stack?" and based on that answer i would derive the range command and assign it to a variable that i can call in my playbook.

I know what i want it to do, but i just can't for the life of me figure out how to execute it in Ansible, i'm completely aware that below is wrong, but hopefully it should give you an idea of what i am trying to achieve?

```
vars_prompt;
  - name: numberOfSwitches
    prompt: 'How many switches in the stack?'
    private: no

if {{ number of switches }} == '4' then
numberOfSwitches='gi1/0/1-48,gi2/0/1-48,gi3/0/1-48,gi4/0/1-48'
```

i can then call this variable in my jinja2 template to configure all access ports on the switch

Sorry again for my noobness :-)

**EDIT**

**Playbook**

```
---

- name: Generate and Deploy Configuration
  hosts: switches
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli
  vars_prompt:

    - name: hostname
      prompt: "What is the hostname?"
      private: no
    - name: dataVlanID
      prompt: "What is the Data Vlan ID?"
      private: no
    - name: dataVlanName
      prompt: "What is the Data Vlan name?"
      private: no
    - name: voiceVlanID
      prompt: "What is the Voice Vlan ID?"
      private: no
    - name: voiceVlanName
      prompt: "What is the Voice Vlan Name?"
      private: no
    - name: snmpLocation
      prompt: "For SNMP, where will this switch be installed?"
      private: no
    - name: mgmtVlanIP
      prompt: "What is the management IP of this switch?"
      private: no

  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: staging
    ansible_ssh_pass: staging
    ansible_network_os: ios
    enableSecret: cisco2
    userName: cisco2
    userPassword: cisco2
    nameServerOne: 10.50.191.3
    nameServerTwo: 10.50.191.131
    startSwitch: 1
    ntpPrefer: 10.50.191.3
    ntpBackup: 10.50.191.131

  tasks:
    - name: Generate Running Configuration 
      template: 
        src="/etc/ansible/jinja2-template/base_with_vars.j2" 
        dest=/etc/ansible/config/{{ inventory_hostname }}_interface.txt
      register: interface

    - name: Push Configuration to Device
      ios_config:
        src: /etc/ansible/config/{{ inventory_hostname }}_interface.txt
      notify: Write Memory
      when: interface.changed

  handlers:
    - name: Write Memory
      ios_command:
        commands: wr
```

**Hosts**

```
[switches]
SW1 ansible_host=10.222.0.131
```

**Jija2 Template**

```
no service pad
service tcp-keepalives-in
service tcp-keepalives-out
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service password-encryption
no service dhcp
!
hostname {{hostname}}
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 1000000
enable secret {{enableSecret}}
!
username {{userName}} privilege 15 secret {{userPassword}}
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login AAA_METHOD_CONSOLE local
aaa authentication login AAA_METHOD_VTY group radius local
aaa authorization commands 0 default if-authenticated 
aaa authorization commands 1 default if-authenticated 
aaa authorization commands 15 default if-authenticated 
!
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
clock timezone AEST 10 0
!
!
!
!
no ip source-route
ip dhcp bootp ignore
!
!
ip dhcp snooping vlan 1-4094
ip dhcp snooping database flash:dhcp-snooping.db
ip dhcp snooping
ip domain-name rccprd.redland.qld.gov.au
ip name-server {{nameServerOne}}
ip name-server {{nameServerTwo}}
login block-for 120 attempts 3 within 30
login on-failure log
login on-success log
vtp domain {{hostname}}
vtp mode transparent
!
!
!
!
vlan 8
 name PRD-RCC-SECURITY
!
vlan 16
 name PRD-RCC-PRINTER
!
!
vlan 56
 name PRD-RCC-WIFI-AD
!
vlan {{dataVlanID}}
 name {{dataVlanName}}
!
vlan {{voiceVlanID}}
 name {{voiceVlanName}}
!
vlan 998
 name PRD_RCC_DEAD-VLAN
!
vlan 999
 name PRD_RCC_NATIVE-VLAN
!
vlan 4000
 name MANAGEMENT_VLAN
!
lldp run
!
!
!
!
interface Vlan4000
 ip address {{mgmtVlanIP}} 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
!
!
!
!
flow record Scrutinizer-Record1
 match datalink mac source address input
 match datalink mac destination address input
 match ipv4 tos
 match ipv4 protocol
 match ipv4 source address
 match ipv4 destination address
 match transport source-port
 match transport destination-port
 collect transport tcp flags
 collect interface input
 collect flow sampler
 collect counter bytes long
 collect counter packets long
 collect timestamp sys-uptime first
 collect timestamp sys-uptime last
!
!
flow exporter Scrutinizer-Export1
 destination 10.50.150.231
 source Vlan4000
 transport udp 2055
 template data timeout 60
 option interface-table
 option exporter-stats
 option sampler-table
!
!
flow monitor Scrutinizer-Monitor1
 exporter Scrutinizer-Export1
 cache timeout active 60
 statistics packet protocol
 record Scrutinizer-Record1
!
!
archive
 path flash:/Config-Archive/
 write-memory
memory reserve critical 4096
memory free low-watermark processor 20
memory free low-watermark IO 20
!
spanning-tree mode mst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
spanning-tree mst configuration
 name RCC-MST
 instance 1 vlan 1-4094
!
spanning-tree mst 1 priority 61440
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
 description LACP to HO HP Core
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,2,8,16,48,56,121,621,4000
 switchport trunk native vlan 999
 switchport mode trunk
 ip dhcp snooping trust
!
interface range GigabitEthernet{{startSwitch}}/0/1-48
 description Client Access Port
 switchport access vlan {{dataVlanID}}
 switchport voice vlan {{voiceVlanID}}
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 10
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security aging time 1440
 switchport port-security
 ip flow monitor Scrutinizer-Monitor1 input
 storm-control broadcast level 80.00 50.00
 storm-control multicast level 80.00 50.00
 storm-control action trap
 spanning-tree portfast edge
!
!
ip default-gateway 10.2.0.254
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip ssh time-out 10
ip ssh source-interface Vlan4000
ip ssh version 2
!
ip access-list standard SNMP-SERVERS
 permit 10.50.150.232
 permit 10.50.150.231
 permit 10.50.150.20
 permit 10.50.220.35
 permit 10.50.220.28
 permit 10.50.220.29
 permit 10.50.220.27
 deny   any log
!
kron occurrence KRON-OCC-0200 at 2:00 recurring
 policy-list KRON-POL-SAVE-CONFIG
!
kron occurrence KRON-OCC-0300 at 3:00 recurring
 policy-list KRON-POL-SCP-CONFIG
!
kron policy-list KRON-POL-SAVE-CONFIG
 cli wr 
!
kron policy-list KRON-POL-SCP-CONFIG
 cli copy running-config scp://admin:rgrs753jlh@10.50.40.170/{{hostname}}/
!
logging origin-id hostname
logging facility local6
logging source-interface Vlan4000
logging host 10.50.220.63
logging host 10.50.150.20
!
snmp-server group RCC-SNMP-GROUP v3 priv read SNMPv3-RO-VIEW access SNMP-SERVERS
snmp-server view SNMPv3-RO-VIEW internet included
snmp-server trap-source Vlan4000
snmp-server location {{snmpLocation}}
snmp-server contact IT Service Desk (07) 3829 8432
snmp-server chassis-id {{hostname}}
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart
snmp-server enable traps config
snmp-server enable traps cpu threshold
snmp-server enable traps vlancreate
snmp-server enable traps vlandelete
snmp-server enable traps envmon fan shutdown supply temperature status
!
!
radius server RADIUS-POOL
 address ipv4 10.50.220.62 auth-port 1645 acct-port 1646
 key 7 0214325C06045D17790F28352F54260A19060B6F122D0B760631322F2719027E7C5C711A0E4C52480F706A5D5C615F54372D6C0306362C14481801280C6B401F2B
!
banner exec ^CC
#######################################################################
# This computer system is for authorised use only.                    #
# Users have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy.          #
# Any or all uses of this system and all data on this system may      #
# be intercepted, monitored, recorded, copied, audited, inspected,    #
# and disclosed to authorised sites and law enforcement personnel,    #
# as well as authorised officials of other agencies.                  #
# By using this system, you consent to such disclosure at the         #
# discretion of authorised site personnel.                            #
# Unauthorised or improper use of this system may result in           #
# administrative disciplinary action, civil and criminal penalties.   #
# By continuing to use this system you indicate your awareness of     #
# and consent to these terms and conditions of use. STOP IMMEDIATELY  #
# if you do not agree to the conditions stated in this warning.       #
#######################################################################
^C
banner login ^CC 
#######################################################################
# This computer system is for authorised use only.                    #
# Users have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy.          #
# Any or all uses of this system and all data on this system may      #
# be intercepted, monitored, recorded, copied, audited, inspected,    #
# and disclosed to authorised sites and law enforcement personnel,    #
# as well as authorised officials of other agencies.                  #
# By using this system, you consent to such disclosure at the         #
# discretion of authorised site personnel.                            #
# Unauthorised or improper use of this system may result in           #
# administrative disciplinary action, civil and criminal penalties.   #
# By continuing to use this system you indicate your awareness of     #
# and consent to these terms and conditions of use. STOP IMMEDIATELY  #
# if you do not agree to the conditions stated in this warning.       #
#######################################################################
^C
configuration mode exclusive
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
 login authentication AAA_METHOD_CONSOLE
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 30 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 login authentication AAA_METHOD_VTY
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 exec-timeout 30 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 login authentication AAA_METHOD_VTY
 transport input ssh
!
exception memory ignore overflow processor
exception memory ignore overflow io
ntp source Vlan4000
ntp server {{ntpPrefer}} prefer
ntp server {{ntpBackup}}
!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: numberOfSwitches
      prompt: 'How many switches in the stack?'
      private: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_switches: "{{ my_switches|default([]) +
                       [ 'gi' ~ item ~ '/0/1-48' ] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(1, numberOfSwitches|int + 1, 1)|list }}"
    - template:
        src: my_switches.j2
        dest: /tmp/my_switches.conf
```

with this template

```
$ cat my_switches.j2
{{ my_switches|join(", ") }}
```

gives

```
$ cat /tmp/my_switches.conf
gi1/0/1-48, gi2/0/1-48, gi3/0/1-48, gi4/0/1-48
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answer Vladimir! So would i merge this with my existing playbook, templates and output file? i need one long configuration file to push to the device/s, and i don't have the knowledge to figure out how to squeeze this into those files, i might edit my original post to give more context.....sorry to waste your time guys....

Comment: Wouldn't it be straightforward? Don't hesitate to ask. You might want to update (edit) the question if you have any trouble.